# Math.floor function not working as expected on double variable

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(-3.1759D, -3.175D));
    System.out.println(areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(3.174D, 3.175D));
    System.out.println(areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(-3.0D, -3.0D));
}

public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double num1, double num2) {
    float f = (float) Math.abs(num1 - num2)*1000f;
    double d = Math.abs(num1 - num2)*1000d;
    //double d = 1.000000d;
    System.out.println(String.format("double: %f  float: %f%nd: %f\t\t  f: %f", Math.floor(d), Math.floor(f), d, f));

    return Math.floor(f) < 1;
}}
```

---

In the code above, I am attempting to verify if two double values sent as parameters to `areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces()` are equal up/down to 3 decimal places. Within this method, I have tried to understand why `Math.floor()` with the double variable `d` is not working as expected after assigning a calculated value using `Math.abs() * 1000d`. It seemed to work for the `float` variable `f` after I use the `float` type cast on `Math.abs()` - this left me a bit confused. Why is the `Math.floor()` function not working as expected for the `double` variable `d` as it seems to be working for the `float` variable `f`?

Output:

---

```
double: 0.000000  float: 0.000000
d: 0.900000       f: 0.900000
true
double: 0.000000  float: 1.000000
d: 1.000000       f: 1.000000
false
double: 0.000000  float: 0.000000
d: 0.000000       f: 0.000000
true

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is the output I get with the code above. Here the `double:` and `float:` sections are the output of the `Math.floor(d)` and `Math.floor(f)`. The unexpected behavior happens with the second set of values sent by `main()` the values given by this command `System.out.println(areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(3.174D, 3.175D));`. For the `double` variable `d` the output is expected to look just like the output for `float` variable `f`, however the `Math.floor(d)` returns `0.000000` where I expected it to be `1.000000`.

Comment: Please include what you expected as output and what you got.

Comment: Floats and Doubles can only approximately represent decimal fractions. Depending on rounding effects, the difference may be higher or lower than expected. Your specific test (equal by three decimal places) is ill-defined, there is no proper solution using binary floating point arithmetics.

Answer (score -1):

Substitute your last print statement by this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("double: %2.15f  float: %f%nd: %2.15f\t\t  f: %f", Math.floor(d), Math.floor(f), d, f));
```

This prints the numbers with more decimal places. Then you can see that `d` is really less than `1`. This happens because floating point numbers (as double or float) usually cannot represent decimal values exactly.

This is due to the fact that floating point numbers are represented as binary values (base 2) internally. So in decimal representation 1/5 is exactly 0.2, but it is an infinite floating point number in a representaton with base 2, like 1/3 is in decimal representation 0.333... .

Comment: It would be even better to print `new BigDecimal(d)` instead of `d`, to get the exact decimal value. `%2.15f` may not be the whole truth.

Comment: I'm somewhat uncomfortable with the final sentence here - floating point numbers *are* exact values, they're just not necessarily the exact result of a previous operation. For example, if you had a floating point types with two decimal digits and tried to represent 1/3, the result would be *exactly* 0.33, but that's not exactly "one third". It's the *operations* that are approximations, not the values themselves.

Comment: @Roland Illig, yes `%2.15f` may not be the whole truth, but it is suffcient here to show cause of the problem.

Comment: The `%2.15f` is only sufficient here by coincidence. It could as well lead into the wrong direction because of rounding errors, which is the exact problem leading to this question after all. Therefore it is a bad advice as it doesn't work reliably in similar situations. To give useful answers and get upvotes, you should rather write answers that work in all situations and improve the asker's knowledge.